Building fields from the Kallen-Lehmann representation formula
The standard QFT textbook presentation is usually such that the Lagrangian/theory is given first and then things like the 2-point function, propagator, and Kallen-Lehmann representation are derived as a consequence.
When defining generalized free fields in axiomatic quantum field theory the approach seems to be other way around. Let $W_2$ be the 2-point function of an arbitrary spin-0 theory. Then the formula given in AQFT is that
$$W_2(x,y) = \int_0^\infty \Delta_m^+(x-y) d\rho(m^2) \tag{1}$$
where
$$\Delta_m^+ = \int e^{ip\cdot x} \delta(m^2 + p^2) \Theta(p_0) dp, \tag{2}$$
$p$ is a momentum $4$-vector, and $\Theta$ is the Heaviside function. The key idea behind (1) is that there exists a positive measure $\rho$ such that (1) is true.
My understanding is that in AQFT the idea is to use (1) as a starting point and we can define different fields by our choice of the positive measure $\rho$. Is this correct? For example, by choosing $\rho$ to be a delta function we get the usual free field. My questions are:

What is the physical content of (1) and (2)?
If we have for example a $\phi^4$ interaction, can $\rho$ be chosen to obtain the 2-point function of the interacting theory?
In particle physics textbooks the Kallen-Lehmann representation is described as a sum/integral of propagators multiplied by a spectral density. How does this agree with (1) which contains no propagators? By choosing $\rho$ to be a delta function then we have $W_2 = \Delta_m^+$, and so it seems this is indeed the free theory propagator but (2) is different than the usual expression for the time ordered propagator, which in $4D$ looks like: $$G(x,y) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^4} \int d^4p \frac{e^{-ip\cdot(x-y)}}{p^2 - m^2 \pm i\epsilon}.$$ I think this means the spectral density is part of the measure $\rho$?


I'll refrain from answering 1 as the physicality of generalized free fields is not clear to me. For example,the validity of locality properties such as Haag duality, the time-slice axiom, or even the (strong) commutativity of the time-zero fields can all fluctuate as a function of the spectral density defining the free field. They seem to me to simply serve as a source of simple examples of field theories in order to examine certain generic axiomatic properties.
The answer to 2 is yes. You can take $\rho$ to be any tempered measure,  so in particular you can construct a generalized free field to have the 2-point function of any interacting field that you ask for.
As for 3, you can straightforwardly relate the $\epsilon$-regularized expression for the Feynman propagator and the explicit one by evaluating the contour integral using Cauchy's residue theorem.

Thank you. So in some sense the choice of the measure $\rho$ determines the theory? Doesn't the propagator already do this?

Yes the measure determines the generalized free field (but of course not in general- many inequivalent Wightman fields can have the same 2-point function, as this example also demonstrates). Also the time-ordered propagator determines the wightman function which determines the generalized free field. The Wightman function is just generally a more natural object in many scenarios.

To make sure I have understood this correctly, the propagator is fixed once we specify the properties of the theory (e.g. massive and spin 0, I'm not too clear on this but perhaps this should be asked in a separate question). Then by choosing any positive measure $\rho$ we can use the Kallen-Lehmann representation to define the 2-point Wightman function. If the $n$-point functions are able to be completely determined by the 2-point functions then we have a generalized free field. Is this all correct?

Spin and mass describe irreducible representations, which correspond to free fields. Generalized free fields are far more general and require the full spectral measure in order to specify. Suppose you specify such a spectral measure. Then you have a generalized free field if you specifically have that the n-point functions are related to the 2-point function by Wick's theorem.

If we do not specify spin, mass, or have a Lagrangian then how do we determine the propagators $\Delta^+_m$ as a starting point?

The point is that there is a distribution of masses. The precise distribution is given by the spectral measure. If there is only one mass in the theory, then you can just take $\rho = \delta_{m_0^2}$ for $m_0$ your given mass. As for spin, there's a more general Kallen-Lehmann representation of essentially the same form that accommodates general spin fields. I think you can find an account of this more general theorem in Bogolyubov's General Principles of Quantum Field Theory.

But before one chooses a measure how would one determine the propagator $\Delta^+$ if we do not have a Lagrangian?

You mean the $\Delta_m^+$ in the Kallen-Lehmann representation theorem? You should look into the proof. There is a nice one in Reed-Simon volume 2. A Lagrangian never comes into the picture (and generally never does in axiomatic quantum field theory). Instead the theorem comes entirely from temperedness and Lorentz covariance. With this kind of stuff it's good practice to separate formalism common in physics (perturbative Lagrangian field theory) from the pure physical principles.

Thank you for all your help!
